# Generate XSD from SOAP Response XML

Tags: xml, soap, xsd

I have a SOAP response XML and I need a XSD for that XML. I have tried online conversions, XMLBeans and java but I am not getting an appropiate XSD for my XML. Can anyone tell me how can I do the conversion.
The SOAP response XML is below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:sessionID soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.polarion.com/session">-1897751301705602409</ns1:sessionID>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <logInResponse xmlns="http://ws.polarion.com/SessionWebService-impl"/>
</soapenv:Body>
```

</soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

Getting an "appropriate" XSD is something only a human being can do: you need to understand the data model represented by the XML. For example, in your example, the logInResponse element is empty, but only you can decide whether it will *always* be empty.

If you don't really care about what the validation rules are, but just need a schema for the sake of ticking a box, then you can always use a generic schema that allows anything. Unfortunately though, that's not as easy as it should be, because a strict schema validator insists on the schema having an explicit global element declaration for the outermost element. So the minimal schema is something like

```
<xs:element name="logInResponse"/>
```

(in the right targetNamespace, of course).